# What are the console colour values

Tags: c#, console

The ConsoleColor.Red code will give you the colour red right. The code (ConsoleColor)3746 will give you another colour. But what is this number (rgb,hex) and how do I convert into an rgb value of vice versa.

Comment: Look here: http://www.rapidtables.com/web/color/RGB_Color.htm

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.consolecolor(v=vs.110).aspx It is described as an enumeration of a selection of colours.  As such there is no requirement that the enumerable value represents the actual colour content in any way at all (although that would imply that there is a list to convert them somewhere in mscorlib.dll).  Try experimenting with different numbers and if sequential values generate wildly different colours then it's probably using a look-up list.

Answer (score 8):

First, let's see the colors

```
var colors = Enum.GetValues(typeof(ConsoleColor)).Cast<ConsoleColor>();

foreach (var color in colors)
{
    Console.BackgroundColor = color;
    Console.WriteLine(color);
}
```

[image: Console Colors]

The world of console colors is 4 bit: one each for red, green and blue, and 1 for intensity, which doubles the saturation of the given color (except for Gray / White). This gives is 15 possible distinct colors. The corresponding hex would be 0, 80 and FF for each of red, green and blue:

```
Name         R    G    B
-------------------------
Black        00   00   00
DarkBlue     00   00   80
DarkGreen    00   80   00
DarkCyan     00   80   80
DarkRed      80   00   00
DarkMagenta  80   00   80
DarkYellow   80   80   00
DarkGray     80   80   80
Blue         00   00   FF
Green        00   FF   00
Cyan         00   FF   FF
Red          FF   00   00
Magenta      FF   00   FF
Yellow       FF   FF   00
Gray         C0   C0   C0
White        FF   FF   FF
```

Note that 'Gray' is the odd one out. The reason for this is that 4 bits actually allows 16 colors, but only 15 can be uniquely encoded for in the off-on-on+intensity scheme.